# Pandas to slice date alike string and rearrange to date format

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date

A column in the dataframe looks like DD/MM/YYYY format.

I want to slice it and rearrange to MM/DD/YYYY (for calculation)

I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csvfile = StringIO("""
DD/MM/YYYY
01/05/2020
21/02/2021
19/06/2021
05/06/2021
11/06/2021
10/05/2021
")

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = ',', engine='python')

df['DD/MM/YYYY'] = df['DD/MM/YYYY'].astype(str)

df['MM/DD/YYYY'] = df['DD/MM/YYYY'][3:5] + '/' + df['DD/MM/YYYY'][:2] + '/' + df['DD/MM/YYYY'][-4:]

# df['MM/DD/YYYY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DD/MM/YYYY'][3:5] + '/' + df['DD/MM/YYYY'][:2] + '/' + df['DD/MM/YYYY'][-4:])

print (df)
```

But it doesn't work. What would be the right way to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.str`:

```
df['MM/DD/YYYY'] = df['DD/MM/YYYY'].str[3:5] + '/' + df['DD/MM/YYYY'].str[:2] + '/' + df['DD/MM/YYYY'].str[-4:]
```

If possible you can parse datetimes by original format in specified in `format='%d/%m/%Y'` and then add [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['MM/DD/YYYY']  = pd.to_datetime(df['DD/MM/YYYY'], format='%d/%m/%Y').st.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```